# How can I restrict a Google search, using custom search api (CSE), to last hour?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-search-api

As from the title, I'm trying to write a service, with NodeJs, that performs a CES restricted to last hour. 
In the documentation the only param regarding limitation time seems to be **dateRestrict** which as smallest portion of time gives you **days**, so `dateRestrict=1d`

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list